# how to prove that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let Q be the unit square in $R^2$. Consider functions $f_n\in L^1(Q)$ such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere in Q and $\int_{Q}|f_n|\to \int_{Q} |f|<\infty $

(a)prove that $\int_A|f_n|\to \int_A |f| $ for every measurable subset A of Q

(b)prove that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$

I am just thinking about whether I can use Fatou's theorem to prove part(a), but still have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Of course if you prove (b), then (a) follows.

Comment: yeah-----, but how can I prove part (b)? any hint?

Comment: Egorov's theorem may be helpful here if you know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply Fatou's Lemma to $|f_n| + |f| -|f_n-f|.$ (A classic application, but not so obvious on your first encounter.)